# Aligning the rows of a CSV

Tags: python, bash, csv

I have a CSV with three columns. Each column has mostly the same data, but occasionally there is an entry missing so that everything in the column is shifted up and the rows become unaligned. I would like to make the CSV so that each row has the same entry. I chose "bash" and "python" as flair because I know those are installed on my Linux machine. Any other method that can work on a Linux machine without third party tools will be accepted.

For example, I have this CSV:

```
1,2,1
3,3,2
4,5,5
6,6,7
7,7,8
8,8,9
```

and I would like to change it to:

```
1,,1
,2,2
3,3,
4,,
,5,5
6,6,
7,7,7
8,8,8
,,9
```

In the initial CSV, each column is sorted alphabetically/numerically.

Each row in the output can have the same value in any number of columns in that row. For example, in the first row - 1 can be in column 1, 2, or 3 or any all of them. I do not want to "add" a 1 in the first row, second column. I would like to insert a blank into the first row, second column pushing each entry of column two down. This way, all the "twos" are on the same row (for the columns that have a two) and all the "threes" are on the same row, etc.

The actual values in my CSV are different than above. I used the above values to keep it simple. If it matters, my values will be up to 15 alphanumeric characters, followed by an underscore, then three numbers. Example: ABCDE14915_429. If you feel that more realistic values would make a better example, they are below:

Input

```
ABCDE12345_001,FGHIJ6789_002,ABCDE12345_001
KLMNO5432_003,KLMNO5432_003,FGHIJ6789_002
PQRST24680_123,UVWXY13579_555,UVWXY13579_555,
ZABCD876530_009,ZABCD876530_009,7
AABBCCDDEE_987,AABBCCDDEE_987,LMNOP98765_999
LMNOP98765_999,ZYXWV54321_777,ZYXWV54321_777
```

Output

```
ABCDE12345_001,,ABCDE12345_001
,FGHIJ6789_002,FGHIJ6789_002
KLMNO5432_003,KLMNO5432_003,
PQRST24680_123,,
UVWXY13579_555,UVWXY13579_555,
ZABCD876530_009,ZABCD876530_009,
AABBCCDDEE_987,AABBCCDDEE_987,AABBCCDDEE_987
LMNOP98765_999,,LMNOP98765_999
,ZYXWV54321_777,ZYXWV54321_777
```

Maybe this picture will help. Columns ABC are my input CSV values. I would like output CSV values to look like columns EFG.

[image: Spreadsheet Example]

or if you like the "real" values

[image]

Comment: Is it always 2 equal and 1 different on each row?

Comment: Please show what you tried. We'll help you fix it, we won't write it for you.

Comment: It shouldn't matter what the values are. You're just comparing strings, they could be anything.

Comment: would a 'complete'  set consist of the extract string `ABCDE14915_429` residing in each column? if not then it may be more beneficial to update the question to include 5-7 lines of your actual data

Comment: if the ordering of the rows maters in the final output then we'll probably need to see some more realistic data along with an indicateion of how the data is to be sorted,  especially if we're talking about values that are variable in length and content (*`values will be up to 15 alphanumeric characters`*)

Comment: 1. No, each string can be in any one or multiples of the three columns. Each column is sorted alphabetically. 
2. I haven't tried anything. I know a little bash, but nothing close enough to what it would take to accomplish this.
3. No. The value could be in any or multiple of the three columns.

Comment: > "If it matters, ..." Of course it matters! The solution has to be able to answer the question: does this field belong to the current row, or does it have to move to another one. In the dummy data that is obvious because the field value is the row number. If `ABCDE14915_429` appears in row 17, how do you know it doesn't belong there? Is `429` the row where it should be?

Comment: what is the expected max size (MBytes) of the data file? based on the expected output (of the more realistic data) there doesn't appear to be any requirement to generate said output in any particular order .... is this a correct observation?

Comment: What happened to the `7` in `ZABCD876530_009,ZABCD876530_009,7`? It doesn't appear in the output.

Comment: `AABBCCDDEE_987` only shows up in the first 2 columns but the expected output shows it in all 3 columns; this doesn't appear to match your description; or is this a typo?  if this is a typo then please update the question to insure the sample input and expected output match (including the issue with the missing `7`)

Comment: similar issue with `UVWXY13579_555` ... shows up in the 2nd and 3rd columns of the input, but shows up in the 1st and 2nd columns of the expected output; typo? or incomplete description?

Comment: while these may sound like nitpicking keep in mind we're limited to exactly what you post; if we come up with a solution but it doesn't generate your expected output then we're left *guessing* if you made a typo or you've left out some details in the description

Comment: you state you know *`a little bash`* while you've tagged the question with `bash` and `python`; I take this to imply that you (may) have an idea on how to do this in `python` and if this is the case then please update the question with your `python` code and the (wrong) output generated by said code

Comment: Three copies of `AABBCCDDEE_987` appear in your sample output, versus only two in the input.  You have a spurious column in the input due to an extra comma. The output is not alphabetically sorted. The first row should be of `AABBCCDDEE_987` values not `ABCDE12345_001`.  Or else, please clarify the rule by which we know which value belongs to which row.

Comment: You said "each column is sorted alphabetically", but that's not true in your sample data.  If it were, this task would be easy.

Comment: Assuming the columns really should be sorted, here's a solution for you:  https://gist.github.com/timrprobocom/09bf78e52ee56018fa7e4e35f035b057

Comment: Solution in [TXR](https://nongnu.org/txr): https://pastebin.com/raw/KzvPE3Wm

Comment: @Arindrew: I went for a solution that doesn't assume or deal with sorting; like you stated it has the effect of just pushing values down till a row comprises a single, unique value: https://gist.github.com/zacharysyoung/ea4d71155dd5c7d408c7d061469a9d9e

Answer (score 1):

I went for a solution that doesn't presuppose any kind of sorting: it just looks for a value and remembers in which column (on any row) it appeared.

Starting with this input:

```
a,b,a
c,c,b
d,e,e
f,f,g
g,g,h
h,h,i
```

It generates a map of values to positions:

```py
{
    "a": [0, 2],
    "b": [1, 2],
    "c": [0, 1],
    "d": [0],
    "e": [1, 2],
    "f": [0, 1],
    "g": [2, 0, 1],
    "h": [2, 0, 1],
    "i": [2],
}
```

From the map, it iterates over the values and writes each value into its own row, in the found positions (columns):

```
a,,a
,b,b
c,c,
d,,
,e,e
f,f,
g,g,g
h,h,h
,,i
```

Since it doesn't presuppose sorting, this:

```
b,a,a
d,d,d
c,e,e
```

becomes:

```py
{
    "b": [0],
    "a": [1, 2],
    "d": [0, 1, 2],
    "c": [0],
    "e": [1, 2],
}
```

becomes:

```
b,,
,a,a
d,d,d
c,,
,e,e
```

This (formatted for legibility):

```
| ABCDE12345_001  | FGHIJ6789_002   | ABCDE12345_001 |
| KLMNO5432_003   | KLMNO5432_003   | FGHIJ6789_002  |
| PQRST24680_123  | UVWXY13579_555  | UVWXY13579_555 |
| ZABCD876530_009 | ZABCD876530_009 | AABBCCDDEE_987 |
| AABBCCDDEE_987  | AABBCCDDEE_987  | LMNOP98765_999 |
| LMNOP98765_999  | ZYXWV54321_777  | ZYXWV54321_777 |
```

becomes:

```
| ABCDE12345_001  |                 | ABCDE12345_001 |
|                 | FGHIJ6789_002   | FGHIJ6789_002  |
| KLMNO5432_003   | KLMNO5432_003   |                |
| PQRST24680_123  |                 |                |
|                 | UVWXY13579_555  | UVWXY13579_555 |
| ZABCD876530_009 | ZABCD876530_009 |                |
| AABBCCDDEE_987  | AABBCCDDEE_987  | AABBCCDDEE_987 |
| LMNOP98765_999  |                 | LMNOP98765_999 |
|                 | ZYXWV54321_777  | ZYXWV54321_777 |
```

```py
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

value_positions = defaultdict(list)

with open("input4.csv", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        for i, val in enumerate(row):
            value_positions[val].append(i)

N_COLS = 3

with open("output.csv", "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for val, positions in value_positions.items():
        row = [""] * N_COLS
        for x in positions:
            row[x] = val
        writer.writerow(row)
```